# facing issue while using two setState function continuously

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
<AddInvoiceModal
            open={openShipmentModal}
            shipmentDetails={invoiceShipment}
            origin={userParams?.operation === "LOADING"}
            onClose={() => {
                setShipmentModal(false)
                setInvoiceShipment({})
            }}
            onSuccess={() => {
                setShipmentModal(false)
                updateQueryGateOut()
            }}
        />
```

setInvoiceShipment({}) state in my below code is getting updated first but I want my setShipmentModal state to be updated first.

Comment: Setting state is not synchronous. You don't have control of this. If `setInvoiceShipment` depends on `setShipmentModal`, you may need to use a useEffect?

Answer (score 1):

Since the setState is asynchronous, you have no control over the order of its execution, if you want the invoiceShipment to be set after shipmentModal, you can use the setState function of invoiceShipment inside the useEffect function that tracks the change in shipmentModal,
This makes sure that, the invoiceShipment is only set to {} after the shipmentModal has been changed.
For example,

```
onClose(() => {
    setShipmentModal(false)
}
useEffect(() => {
    if(shipmentModal === false) {
        setInvoiceShipment({})
    }
}, [shipmentModal])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update state by event handler action, we need to use useEffect with ref for state update, because state update in react is asynchronous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since the setState is asynchronous and the execution time of the first function might be higher than the second one, you cant' be sure that the execution order will be maintained.

You probably need to use an useEffect that clear the invoiceShipment state on the shippingModal flag reset. Something like this

```
useEffect((){
 if(!shipmentModal){
  setInvoiceShipment({})
 }
}, [shipmentModal])
```

and update the existing onClose event handler

```
onClose={() => {
       setShipmentModal(false)
       // setInvoiceShipment({}) REMOVE
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack to delay the execution of `setInvoiceShipment`:

```
onClose={() => {
    setShipmentModal(false)
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInvoiceShipment({})
    }, 1);
}}
```